# Print two presorted lists into one output file in python

Tags: python, list, file-io, merge

I have two lists that are already sorted how they need to be, and i need them put into one file, like this example:

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d, e]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

output file should look like:

```
a1
b2
c3
d4
e5
```

im fairly new to python, so im not really all that sure how to do file writing. I read using `with open(file, 'w') as f:` is a better/easier way to start the writing block, but i am unsure how to merge the lists and print them as such. I could probably merge them into a third list and print that one to the file using `print>>f, item` but i wanted to see if there was as simpler way.

Thank you!

Late edit: looking at my lists, they wont always be the same length, but all the data needs printed regardless. So if list2 went to 7 then then the output would need to be:

```
a1
b2
c3
d4
e5
6
7
```

or vice versa, where list1 may be longer then list2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function to combine (ie zip) your two lists. E.g.,

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

zip(list1, list2)
```

gives:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

you can then format the output to suit your needs.

```
for i,j in zip(list1, list2):
    print '%s%d' %(i,j)
```

yielding:

```
a1
b2
c3
d4
e5
```

**Update**:

If your lists are unequal length, this approach using
[itertools.izip_longest()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) might work for you:

```
import itertools
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

for i,j in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2): 
    if i: sys.stdout.write('%s' %i)
    if j: sys.stdout.write('%d' %j)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

gives:

```
a1
b2
c3
d
e
```

Note, if you were using Python 3, there is a nice way to use the `print()` function. I am using `write()` here to avoid extra blank spaces between items.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to be working. I changed `%d%d` to `%s%s` since in my program its techincally string (sorry never specified). Is there a way to modify this so that if one list was longer then the other it would still print out all the values (even if they didnt have a match)?

Comment: hm i assume that the `map` statement from this link would go before your for loop?

Comment: hm this works but gives some nuts looking output. It is correct, but each line is in parenthesis, and each item has single quotes around it. Is this a "feature" of using itertools or can i trim this stuff off somehow?

Comment: whoops nevermind i fixed it, thank you so much! I used the itertools line from your edit and `print>>f, '%s%s' %(i,j)` for the second line (for anyone in the future that wants to know)

Answer (score 2):

you should use `zip` function:

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

```
for a, b in zip(lis1, list2):
write(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> map(lambda x:x[0]+str(x[1]),zip(list1,list2))
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5']
```

without `zip()`:

```
>>> map(lambda x,y:x+str(y), list1,list2)
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5']
```

**EDIT:** `If the list2 is list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7]` then use `izip_longest`

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [y[0]+str(y[1]) if y[0]!=None  else y[1] for y in izip_longest(list1,list2,fillvalue=None)]
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5', 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
print "\n".join(("%s%s" % t for t in zip(list1, list2)))
```

Comment: `print "\n".join(("%s%s" % t for t in zip(list1, list2)))` is shorter :)

Comment: @MariaZverina haha nice, been a while since I pythoned. forgot that you dont need to be explicit about tuple expansion

Answer (score 0):

Simples ... love thy Python :)

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> L1 = list("abcde")
>>> L2 = range(1,8)
>>> [(x if x != None else '') + str(y) for (x,y) in izip_longest(L1,L2)]
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5', '6', '7']
>>> print '\n'.join([(x if x != None else '') + str(y) for (x,y) in izip_longest(L1,L2)])
a1
b2
c3
d4
e5
6
7
```